# How to find how many web pages Nutch crawled?

Tags: web-crawler, nutch

At the end of a Nutch crawl, is it possible to find or determine how many web pages Nutch actually crawled?

Answer (score 2):

use the [readdb](https://wiki.apache.org/nutch/bin/nutch_readdb) command with -stats, this will give you the breakdown per status

Comment: bin/nutch readdb crawl -stats gives error. InvalidInputException. .../crawl/current doesn't exist.
I have not touched the crawl directory after the crawl finished.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `readdb`

```
bin/nutch readdb crawl/crawldb -stats
```

Example : `bin/nutch readdb crawl/dabfolder/crawldb -stats`

**Output will be like :**

```
Statistics for CrawlDb: crawl/dabfolder/crawldb/
TOTAL urls: 563390
shortest fetch interval:    30 days, 00:00:00
avg fetch interval: 30 days, 00:43:49
longest fetch interval: 45 days, 00:00:00
earliest fetch time:    Fri Jun 02 11:57:00 IST 2017
avg of fetch times: Sun Jun 04 14:46:00 IST 2017
latest fetch time:  Mon Jul 17 11:54:00 IST 2017
retry 0:    560279
retry 1:    3111
min score:  0.0
avg score:  0.1028828
max score:  195.854
status 1 (db_unfetched):    524278
status 2 (db_fetched):  17615
status 3 (db_gone): 1143
status 4 (db_redir_temp):   8428
status 5 (db_redir_perm):   11800
status 7 (db_duplicate):    126
CrawlDb statistics: done
```